# Is it possible to project an ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer using the JS API?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, coordinate-system

I need to project some dynamic layers to Web Mercator. The geometry service only projects geometries. Is there a geo-processing tool in ArcMap for this? Or any suggestions how i could do this without altering the map services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a dynamic map service, you can simply request it in a different coordinate system using the [spatialreference](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer-amd.html#spatialreference) parameter.

Lets assume you already have a map defined in your javascript app, with a spatial reference of 4326 (web mercator), by simply adding the dynamic 
map service, (with a differing supported spatial reference) it will automatically re-project its map contents to match the map's spatial reference.

See [this code sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/map_customextent_and_sr.html) which shows how you can define a custom extent and spatial reference, and then add a dynamic map service on top, and it will reproject it self to match the coordinate system.  Note that there is a performance hit for doing the reprojection.